# Putting a non-integer number as a radius of a circle

Tags: calculations

I recently embarked the journey of learning LaTeX and there are some caveats to overcome. I tried to draw circles with radius 2, 3, 4 cm but the code does not generate when I try with an irrational number such as `\sqrt{2}`. What should I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The code snippet `\sqrt{2}` does *not* produce a numeric value. Instead, it tells LaTeX to typeset, you guessed it, `\sqrt{2}`. If you need to generate the number `1.4142...`, run something like `\directlua{tex.sprint(math.sqrt(2))}` (if you use LuaLaTeX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said Mico in comments, instead od `\sqrt{2}` you should use `sqrt(2), so:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz\draw (0,0) circle[radius=sqrt(2)];
\end{document}
```

It works with pdfLaTeX as well with LuaLaTeX.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The way you wrote it is different, but I realised that I should write the radius in the form (radius=...) in case of irrational numbers